# change css background of all elements on a page

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the background image of every element on a page by adding a string to it's address in this manner:

Get the back ground image address of an element from the styles:

```
background-image: url("img/sprites.png");
```

Add the string `?ver=3` to it, so it will become like this

```
background-image: url("img/sprites.png?ver=3");
```

I guess I may do that on a single known element by somthing like this:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').style.backgroundImage += "?ver=3"
```

Am I right?

However, I want to do this to all the elements. How can I have the loop access all the elements?

Comment: Every single element in your page has a background-image? Even some elements like `head`, `table` or `select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `document.getElementsByTagName`:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0, len = elms.length; i != len; ++i) {
  elms[i].style.backgroundImage += '?ver=3';
}
```

Or, you could use the DOM to modify the stylesheet object directly. You'd have to write separate codepaths for different browsers, but it would probably run much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using jquery.

```
$("*").css('backgroundImage', $(this).css('backgroundImage')+'?ver=3');
```

I just typed this from memory so it might not be 100% but it seems like it would work.

Possibly this:

```
$("*").each(function(){$(this).css('backgroundImage', $(this).css('backgroundImage')+'?ver=3');});
```

Hope this help a little.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this with jquery:

```
$('*').each(function(){
$(this).css( 'background-image', $(this).css('background-image') + "?ver=3");
});
```

I would prefer to use $('body *') in the selector to not include elements like head and html.

Answer (score 0):

suppose the elements that you want to assign a background to are wrapped in a div with class 'mysprites':

```
<div id="mysprites">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

To let each `sprites.png` version number correspond to the i-th element, just call

```
$('#mysprites').each(function(index) {
$(this).css("background-image", "url(img/sprites.png?ver=" + index + ")");
})
```

like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxwgq/1/)

(if you don't know jquery, just [download](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery) it and add it to the header of your html file like:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```